# Why was the Java App store discontinued?

Tags: java, appstore

A Java App Store sounds like a cool idea right? Well, I turned to Google and found [some](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZyHmLmPyTU) [remnants](http://www.distimo.com/blog/2011_01_java-app-store-discontinued-by-sunoracle/) of an app store that Oracle had been developing. It looks like it has since been discontinued, but I haven't been able to find much commentary on why it was abandoned. So why was it discontinued?

Links to other references, for instance blog posts discussing the difficulties of Oracle's app store, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no official story from Oracle as to why they closed the store.

From the [Distimo Blog article "Java App Store discontinued by Sun/Oracle?"](http://www.distimo.com/blog/2011_01_java-app-store-discontinued-by-sunoracle/):

> We have been unable to uncover any official announcement on the matter.

All that is left is speculation ([1](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-app-store-is-dead-sun-oracle), [2](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-app-store-is-dead-sun-oracle)); perhaps Oracle didn't want to deal with the malware potential and PR nightmare, perhaps internal politics killed it. The Store was originally a Sun idea, and when Oracle purchased Sun many Java ideas died quiet deaths.

We'll never know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any links but I seem to recall Oracle were alarmed while observing the press regarding the android store and malware and didn't want to invest in apple style scrutiny.